# Specialist to treat low Sodium

Tags: blood-tests, blood-pressure, sodium

My 74 year old Dad has lower Sodium and Chloride than normal in his bloodwork.

After taking 1/2 teaspoon of salt with his dinner, the Sodium and Chloride levels are still low, but blood pressure is high.

I don't have exact numbers right now, will post as soon as I receive.

I heard low Sodium levels can lead to seizure and stroke. Plus he's depressed at how his life turned out, so that's lot of stress.

The doctor he goes to is not even board certified and she didn't seem concerned by such levels.

Please tell what kind of Specialist can help my dad.

Thank you so much!

#### More Info

In May 2016 Dad went to Pulmonologist, blood pressure was 120/61, yet sodium and chloride were low
Then Dad started taking 1/2 teaspoon of salt with dinner

10 days ago went to Internal Medical Doctor, blood pressure was 140/70 but
Sodium level is 129

Answer (score 2):

No, your dad shouldn't see a hematologist.  Hyponatremia (low plasma sodium levels) has several different causes.  To mention just a few: certain medications, congestive heart failure, certain diseases affecting the kidneys or liver, syndrome of inappropriate anti-diuretic hormone (SIADH), chronic, severe vomiting or diarrhea, drinking too much water, dehydration, adrenal gland insufficiency (Addison's disease), low levels of thyroid hormone, the recreational drug Ecstasy, etc.  Your dad should, therefore, be seen by an internist who will find out what is causing hyponatremia. He will then refer your father to a nephrologist, cardiologist, endocrinologist, depending on his diagnosis. But never a hematologist.

Comment: Your answer will be more appreciated if you could add a reference proving your yet-to-be certified answer

Comment: @Prince  Before criticizing the absence of references in my answer you should provide a real reference to back up your answer that a hematologist is the specialist a patient with low sodium levels should look for.  Your link takes us to a page on multiple myeloma instead.

Comment: From my research, your advice on the use of not going to a hematologist was inadequate, from http://www.rightdiagnosis.com/h/hyponatremia/doctors.htm, you'll see that a hematologist is actually one of the specialist that can help treat low sodium levels. So it would be wise of you to edit your answer.

Comment: +1 for the right answer Centaurus (and I know what I am talking about as I am in the medical field). Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

The type of specialist you should see is a hematologist.

A hematologist is a blood specialist who monitors healthy blood levels, and diagnoses and treats diseases of the blood.

http://www.healio.com/hematology-oncology/news/online/%7Bad3ed5c5-0488-4f09-92aa-429c889c1943%7D/what-is-a-hematologist

http://www.rightdiagnosis.com/h/hyponatremia/doctors.htm

Comment: I am downvoting this answer as by no mean, a hematologist is the specialist  for hyponatremia. From my current experience (I am a medical student currently working at an internal medicine department), hyponatremia can be addressed by a specialist in internal medicine and or nephrologist and or endocrinologist. So Centaurus' answer below is definitely the right one! I can't understand how your answer got upvoted tbh. It's totally misleading...